# Why can I access HTMLElement from jQuery Object with array index operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

As I've tested, `$('foo')` is an instance of `jQuery`, and not an instance of `Array`. And AFAIK, javascript doesn't have operator overloading.

So how can `$('foo')[0]` return the corresponding `HTMLElement` if `$('foo')` is not an instance of `Array`?

I tried to look at jQuery's source code but it's a bit too much for me right now.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you can use brackets notation with any object in JavaScript, not just arrays. In fact, normal arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) in JavaScript, they're just objects with a specific prototype and special treatment of a class of property names ("array indexes") and a special `length` property.

Brackets notation can be used to access any object property<sup>1</sup> via its string name (and believe it or not, `[0]` is converted to `["0"]` when accessing arrays, in theory).

Example:

```js
var obj = {foo: "bar", 0: "zero"};
console.log(obj[0]);     // zero
console.log(obj["0"]);   // zero
console.log(obj.foo);    // bar
console.log(obj["foo"]); // bar
var f = "f" + "o" + "o";
console.log(obj[f]);     // bar
```

The object above has two properties of its own. Their names are `"0"` and `"foo"`; both names are strings (even though I wrote `0` as a numeric literal in the initializer; it gets coerced to string).

jQuery maintains its "array entry" properties to ensure that you can use brackets notation to access them. It also maintains a `length` property.

If jQuery were being written from scratch today, it probably would extend `Array`. But when jQuery was written, you *couldn't* extend `Array`. (It only became possible as of ES2015's ("ES6's") `class` feature.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Except properties that *don't have* a string name; ES2015 introduced the concept of properties with names that are `Symbol`s rather than strings. Prior to that, all object property names were strings (even array indexes).

Comment: I knew all objects in js are hashtables and I can do `obj[0]` where `0` is automatically casted to a string. But it never occured to me that `arr[0]` is exactly the same. `arr[0]` just looks so much like *an array with an index operator to me* XD

Comment: @潘俊杰 Yes indeed. :-) And typed arrays ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-typedarray-objects) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)) really are arrays, but standard arrays aren't. Although it's not correct to say objects are hashtables. *Conceptually* they're name/value pairs with prototypes, but modern JavaScript engines don't just do hashtables, they do runtime-generated classes and subclasses (falling back to "dictionary" mode if you use `delete`).